# Running multiple site-to-site with openvpn

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn

I'm planning to connect two offices in two diffrenet locations with Openvpn, here I know that I can use site-to-site for my purpose, But the offices will grow in the future up to 10 or more and all of them need to be connected with each other.
All the servers are Linux systems and I have to do it only by Openvpn.
Can anybody give me a clue about that?

Comment: There's no problem to have specific offices connected directly using OpenVPN as well as over the "central" server.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little on the vague side, so I am assuming you're addressing the concern of how this scales both in terms of performance and number of processes.

Off-handedly, I suggest you spend some time planning out your IP space so that you have a relationship between physical location and address space. At this point you can make routing decisions based on where packets physically need to go without having to always consult a spreadsheet.

Maintain one tunnel per pair of locations that need to talk to each other, and route across them appropriately.

### All of that said:

One hopes that as your business grows, you are also growing your infrastructure. Point to point OpenVPN tunnels won't be the best solution to scale with you, and in the long term you'll want some type of real WAN, which is definitely outside the scope of your question.

Comment: what are the other choises rather than Openvpn? we may have at least 13 servers

Comment: I was speaking more along the lines of hardware solutions, and that's not something I'm going to try addressing because I'm not really a networking guy.